# How to use numpy empty_like

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got the following array:

```
rxn_probability = [1. 0. 0.]
```

And I want to create another array, num_rxn, that has the same shape and size of rxn_probability, which contains a number of the reactions, so in this case num_rxn would be: [1, 2, 3]. Starting at 1 and increasing until it reaches the same size and shape of rxn_probability, so that if I change the size of rxn_probability the size and shape of num_rxn will automatically be changed.

So far I've tried:

```
num_rxn = np.array(range(len(rxn_probability + 1)))
```

(also tried using arange in a similar way)

But this outputs:

```
[0 1 2]
```

which isn't what I want because it doesn't start at 1 or end at 3.

I've been reading about numpy.empty_like but I'm not sure if that would be the best or right solution. Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: How are you going to change the size of `rxn_probability` without creating a new object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.arange` and then reshape to fit the shape of `rxn_probability`:

```
num_rxn = np.arange(1, rxn_probability.size + 1).reshape(rxn_probability.shape)
```